# Make a custom web control default to self-closing tag in markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web-controls

I have some custom web controls that basically just render a span with content based on their attributes and some calculated info, with no option for child controls. E.g.:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyTag Property1=\"Value\" Property2=\"Value\" />")]
public class MyTag : Control
{
    public String Property1 { get; set; }
    public String Property2 { get; set; }
    public MyTag () {}
    public override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(String.Format("<span class=\"{0}\ id=\"{1}\">{2}</span>",
                                    Property1,
                                    this.ClientID,
                                    Property2));
    }
}
```

To reduce clutter, I'd like the markup to default to self-closing tags when I drop them in from the Toolbox.  Unfortunately, even having ToolboxData defined as a self-closing tag doesn't seem to help.  E.g. dragging and dropping a control from the Toolbox to the markup drops in this:

```
<MyPrefix:MyTag ID="MyTag1" runat="server" Property1="Value" Property2="Value">
</MyPrefix:MyTag>
```

Is there a way to force it to this?

```
<MyPrefix:MyTag ID="MyTag1" runat="server" Property1="Value" Property2="Value" />
```